# Asus M5A97 LE R2.0 failure to post with peculiar PCI card

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, uefi, pci

We have a couple of peculiar PCI cards being used in a circ. 2007 proprietary phone/radio communications logging appliance(WindowsXP PC). Both the card connectors and the old motherboard sockets appear to be standard PCI interfaces.

In attempting to move some of the logging PCs functionality to newer hardware, it has been discovered that the PCI logger cards prevent the new motherboard from POSTing. With the PC speaker plugged in, it gives 8 short beeps followed by another shorter beep of higher pitch.

Information I have seen on the Asus bios lists beep codes only up to 5 beeps.

With the PC speaker unplugged from the new Asus motherboard you can hear the DVD-RAM drive and the hard drive being active while the bootup is "hung". In the old logger the hard drive was in a raid controller that had a single sata output and a 3 pin rs232 header that plugged into a standard serial header on the motherboard.

The old logging appliance will boot either with or without the PCI cards plugged in.

Any ideas what is going on here?
What can I do to get these PCI cards to play nice in the new system?

-

---

### EDIT

The appliance and cards are made by Nice Inc out of Israel. The appliance model is the CallFocus 3. The raid controller with a 3-pin serial port on it is an Accusys ACS75170. The PCI cards are in slots J11 and J12 on the motherboard and linked together at the top by a small ribbon cable on card-edge connectors. They show up in device manager under "Sound, video, and game controllers" and both use the NiceLog.sys 9.6.3.24"(sic) driver.

Nice Ali4

```
Ven: 1712
Dev: 0571
Subsys: 903010B5
CC: 0680
Rev: 02
Memory Range: FDDFF000-FDDFF07F
I/O Range: DF00-DF7F
Memory Range: FDDFE000-FDDFEFFF
I/O Range: DE00-DE3F
IRQ: 16
Location: PCI Slot 6 (PCI bus 3, device 9, function 0)
```

Nice Nati2

```
Ven: 1712
Dev: 0687
Subsys: 903010B5
CC: 0680
Rev: 01
Memory Range: FDDFD000-FDDFD07F
I/O Range: DD00-DD7F
Memory Range: FDDFC000-FDDFCFFF
I/O Range DC00-DC3F
IRQ: 21
Location: PCI Slot 7 (PCI bus 3, device 10, function 0)
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on these "peculiar" cards? Make and model number perhaps?

Comment: Too little information.

Comment: They are proprietary cards with no published documentation, basically a "black box" analog logging interface card. I've added all the information I could find about the cards to the main post.